# Is there any way to reduce time and code for this code

Tags: python, python-3.x, time-complexity

I write a program whose running time is O(n^2) is there any possibility to reduce code and complexity without using nested forloops and inbuilt functions its a matching integer problem and the output is [4,5]

```
a = 12345
b = 49085
l1 = []
l2 = []
l_match = []
while(a != 0):
    c = a % 10
    l1.append(c)
    a //= 10
while(b!= 0):
    d = b % 10
    l2.append(d)
    b //= 10
for i in range(len(l1)):
    for j in range(len(l2)):
        if l1[i] == l2[j]:
            match = l1[i]
            l_match.append(match)
print(l_match)
```

Comment: This type of question is better to be posted on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @Snel23, Please be sure to understand what is [on topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) at code review, before recommending it.  Especially, this code lacks the context that would make a good code review question. Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to print common digits between both numbers @ramabrahmambotla ?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, and correct me if I am wrong, the goal is to find common digits between the two numbers.

If so, an easier way to match common integers is get unique digits from both numbers via a set, and then calculate the intersection between them

```
a = 12345
b = 49085

#Convert both numbers into a set to get unique digits
set_a = set(str(a))
set_b = set(str(b))

#Get common digits between both numbers
common = [int(a) for a in set_a.intersection(set_b)]

print(common)
```

The output will be

```
[5, 4]
```

Comment: thats fine but i want implementation without using inbuilt functions

Comment: set is a standard datatype provided by python, also in your original example you do use list.append which is an inbuilt function again @ramabrahmambotla

Answer (score 2):

You can convert each number to a set of digit characters so that you can use set intersection to obtain the common digits among the two numbers in linear time complexity:

```
list(map(int, set(str(b)).intersection(set(str(a)))))
```

This returns:

```
[4, 5]
```

Comment: Hah! Same approach as mine but terse @blhsing +1 :)

Comment: thats fine but i want implementation without using inbuilt functions

Answer (score 0):

In O(n) time complexity

```
def find_chars_order_n(value1,value2):
  hsh = {}
  resp = set()     #Set is used to have unique Characters
  if str(value1) and str(value2):
    str1 = list(str(value1))
    str2 = list(str(value2))
  for elm in str2:
    hsh[elm] = elm
  for elm in str1:
    if hsh[elm]:
      resp.add(elm)
  # resp = str1 & str2 #using set intersection
  if resp:
    return list(resp))
  else:
    return None

if __name__ == "__main__":
  print(find_chars_order_n(1400,4011))
```